Packages won't install on IDLE in Linux
Reinstalled Linux, to upgrade it to
Linux Mint 21.3
Python 3.11
Installed Idle via Software Manager
Went into terminal and started installing the packages
pip3 install numpy
pip3 install scipy
etc
When I go to try to import anything with Idle it come up 'No module named'
If I go back to terminal and open up the terminal python and try to import numpy it looks like it imports it fine. When I look at the packages installed it shows all of them that I installed with pip3 install, but, I think, anything that wasn't installed with Linux(how do you say) doesn't work, things like bs4 work fine in Idle.
How do I correct the problem and get these darn things to work in Idle?

Sounds like Idle is using a different installed Python version than pip3 is.  The actual version should be visible at the top of Idle's Shell window, or you can run import sys; print(sys.version).

I only have one version of Python installed. OOPS, hit return forgetting that automatically sends the reply. When I check the version i terminal it shows 3.10.12, when I check Idle it shows 3.11..0rc1(or is that an 'l', not sure)

You answered your question... my recommendation is to uninstall idle and evoke it directly from python... Honestly this should have been a case of reading what the package does...
